# Ubuntu 11.10 x64 is not loading after a hard reset.

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure

Hi my system was not resuming from sleep mode so I just did a hard reset (press and hold the power button for reset). Now the system is not loading after booting. Simply cursor is blinking, but if I select the recovery mode it will stop with error message `Failed to spawn friendly-recovery post-stop process`.

Attached the screen shot of the error screen. Nothing is happening after that. Even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> won't work. Please help me.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Gopakumar

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the drive has been put into read only mode, which can be fixed by running a disk check.

### Instructions

- You will need a Live CD/USB.
- Once it boots, open a terminal.
- Type: `sudo fdisk -l`
- Find your hard drive from the list.
- Once you know what it is, run `sudo e2fsk -f /dev/yourdiskhere`
- Allow it to run completely, and allow it to fix any errors.
- Once it completes, close the terminal and the Live System and reboot your computer.